# Stripe API: How do you find the exchange rate and amount in foreign currency of a cross border transfer to a Connect Account?

Tags: payment-processing, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to process payments. I have a platform where international Connect accounts can sell items to others through my platform.

My platform is USD. In this specific example, the Connect account is in CAD (Canada Dollar). When someone purchases an item from this CAD Connect Account, Stripe puts the money in my platform account, leaves my app fee there, and then moves the correct amount into the CAD Connect account. It converts this amount to CAD. In the stripe GUI I can find the **exchange rate** and **amount transferred in CAD**, as circled in the screenshot below. **But** I can't find these attributes in the API.

[image]

The only object I've seen with an `exchange_rate` attribute is the [balance transaction](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions). However, when I get the balance transaction for the transaction in the screenshot, I get this response object:

**Request:** https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance_transactions/txn_1IBNiNLLBOhef2QNqIeaNg9o

**Response:**

```json
{ 
"id": "txn_1IBNiNLLBOhef2QNqIeaNg9o", 
"object": "balance_transaction", 
"amount": -7777, 
"available_on": 1611619200, 
"created": 1611076199, 
"currency": "usd", 
"description": null, 
"exchange_rate": null, 
"fee": 0, 
"fee_details": [], 
"net": -7777, 
"reporting_category": "transfer", 
"source": "tr_1IBNiNLLBOhef2QNcNqv3IlS", 
"status": "pending", 
"type": "transfer" }
```

The problem here is that the balance transaction object above **only shows this transaction in USD**: $77.77 USD came out of my platform account.

But it doesn't show the conversion rate or the amount in CAD. When this $77.00 went into the CAD Connect account, as we can see in the GUI screenshot, that $77.77 was converted to $98.02 CAD and the exchange rate was 1.26039 (USD->CAD).

How can I find this CAD amount and exchange rate through the API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Transfer made to the connected account in this screenshot is in USD. The conversion happens *after the Transfer* itself. The funds are sent in USD and then in the connected account they get converted to that account's default Currency.

You want to look at the Transfer's `destination_payment` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/object#transfer_object-destination_payment) which has the `py_123` id for the Charge on the connected account. That Charge has a BalanceTransaction object (similar to the Transfer one you shared). That BalanceTransaction would reflect the conversion from USD to CAD and surface the exchange rate used in the `exchange_rate` property in that case.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. But I tried it and got an error: I went to this endpoint `https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers/tr_1IBNiNLLBOhef2QNcNqv3IlS?expand[]=destination_payment` to find the balance transaction id. I got:    `{"destination_payment": { "balance_transaction": "txn_1IBNiOLKojKNEaYINS8SFq4t"}}`. Then I used the endpoint `https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance_transactions/txn_1IBNiOLKojKNEaYINS8SFq4t` but I got an error :`"No such balance transaction: 'txn_1IBNiOLKojKNEaYINS8SFq4t'"`. Any idea why?

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to add the Stripe-Account header in the request with the connect account id. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

In case you need to know the currency rate before the actual transaction happens they provide the currency rates [here](https://dashboard.stripe.com/currency_conversion)

HOWEVER, it's only a frontend page and it requires authorization. On top of that, it's updated once every 12 hours. There is no official API that returns currency rates.

There is a small SaaS product that provides stripe currency rates as a REST API.
https://striperates.com/

Comment: Thanks! right now I'm using a free exchange rate api, though it's not ideal. That saas product might be good in the future. I wish stripe just had their  updated rates in the API.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the way I did : I simulated a payment in a foreign currency to a US based account (so that it is presented in US$), then I retrieved the balance transaction associated, and the exchange_rate argument

```
async function exchangeFeesToUS(currency) {

  const paymentIntent = await stripeTestUS.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 10000,
    currency: currency,
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    customer: "ANY_CUSTOMER_WITH_A_PAYMENT_METHOD",
    payment_method: "ANY_CARD_ASSOCIATED_TO_THIS_CUSTOMER",
    confirm: true
  });

  return await balanceTransaction(paymentIntent).then(balance => {
    return balance.exchange_rate
  })

}

async function balanceTransaction(paymentIntent) {

  const chargeId = paymentIntent.charges.data[0].id;

  const charge = await stripeTestUS.charges.retrieve(
    chargeId
  );

  return await stripeTestUS.balanceTransactions.retrieve(
    charge.balance_transaction
  );

}
```

Now, if you want to convert to another currency than the US$, just call the aforementioned function twice :

```
async function exchangeFeesToCUSTOM_CURRENCY(currency) {

  const rate = await exchangeFeesToUS(currency)
  const rateCUSTOM_CURRENCY = await exchangeFeesToUS('your_custom_currency')
  return rate / rateCUSTOM_CURRENCY

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can do

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_live_...";
Transfer transfer = Transfer.retrieve("tr_...");
RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder().setStripeAccount("acct_...").build();
Charge charge = Charge.retrieve(transfer.getDestinationPayment(), requestOptions);
BalanceTransaction balanceTransaction = BalanceTransaction.retrieve(charge.getBalanceTransaction(), requestOptions);
balanceTransaction.getExchangeRate();
balanceTransaction.getNet();
balanceTransaction.getCurrency();
```