# Stripe balance_transaction object is missing

Tags: asp.net, stripe-payments

I have an app that uses the Stripe checkout portal to charge for some services. When a payment is made I am listening for some events on the API webhook endpoint defined for Stripe. The payment is always charged in USD but a Connect account I have is linked to another currency (let's say GBP). One of the events that is triggered from Stripe is **"payment.created"**. In this event we have `balance_transaction` property which you can supposedly use to retrieve the currencies conversion info. But when I try to get this object using **BalanceTransactionService** (.Net) I am getting the following error - `Stripe.StripeException: No such balance transaction`.

What might be the reason I am failing to get this object?

Note: was referencing this answer for a solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801973/8861385.

[image]

Comment: Without code, I cannot really help you. However, I don't really know how you retrieved that charge (or even if you did), but `balance_transaction` is expandable so you can retrieve it and the charge at the same time in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

Since that "payment" is on the connected account that is receiving the transfer, you need to retrieve it while [authenticating as the connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header), if you haven't done that.

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance_transactions/txn_123 \
  -u sk_test_456_platform: \
-H "Stripe-Account: acct_789_connectedaccount"
```